# Double newline when hit enter between php open and close

Tags: php, formatting, atom-editor, hotkeys, emmet

So I use Atom and when I type "php" and hit enter I get

```
<?php | ?>
```

(pretend that line is the cursor)

when I hit enter again write my clean php I get something like

```
<php
|?>
```

when instead I would like something more like

```
<?php
|
?>
```

Kind of like what emmet and atom already do for html.  Is there a hotkey/keybinding or setting for this admittedly very specific but very common instance?  I would prefer nothing else changes about how Atom and emmet does things for formatting. Just with PHP.

Maybe even a way I can change shift + enter from adding a new line under the current to instead inserting a new line where my cursor is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create your own snippet](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/#creating-your-own-snippets) that does that. If you do it that way it shouldn't interfere with any settings from Emmet or the default PHP package.

In your snippets file:

```
'.text.html.php':
  'PHP open/close tags with newline':
    'prefix': 'phpn'
    'body': """
      <?php
      $1
      ?>
    """
```

Then trigger it with `phpn` instead of `php`, or use whatever name you want for the value of `'prefix'`. If you already have other PHP snippets in your snippets file, add the new one under the the existing scope (in this case `'.text.html.php':`).

Comment: Thanks, friend! Works like a charm.